# My visual studio ( 2019 ) doesn't show where the error came from

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I use visual studio 2019 with iisexpress and swagger to test out my APIs, it used to work just fine whenever an error popped in swagger it would show me where the error came from and details about it, then I had to click continue in order to return the error to swagger.
So, whether be it a user handled exception or a common runtime language exception, visual studio used to give me information about that error before it showed it to the user.

However something changed with my settings and now the error doesn't show in my IDE anymore, it directly returns it to swagger which is making my job impossible.

What I have tried so far: Enabling/Disabling Just My Code, reloading symbols, checking that project is running with debug mode. All answers that I found here did not work for me.

If it is of any help, my breakpoints hit normally.

Comment: Check your _Exception Settings_. It is under _Debug/Windows_ menu.The tristate checkbox on _Common Language Runtime Exceptions_ should be in third state for stop on exceptions selected as a default. If the checkbox is checked VS will stop on all exceptions occuring in CLR. You can also expand it and select just that exception type which you are interested in.